# Show category of chain complexes of abelian categories preserves weak homotopy equivalences

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let $F:A\rightarrow B$ be an additive functor of abelian categories.  Then ${\bf Ch_{\geq 0}(F)}$ preserves weak homotopy equivalences.

I've seen this statement in my reading, but no proofs for it.  Does anyone have a link to a proof or a quick proof they can describe to me.

Comment: Assuming that by "weak homotopy equivalences" you mean quasi-isomorphisms (maps that induce isomorphisms on homology), this is false...can you state exactly what all your definitions are?

Comment: By weak homotopy eqivalences I mean maps that induce isomorphism on homotopy groups.  I don't mean quasi-isomorphisms because I don't have that $F$ is exact.

Comment: What is a homotopy group of a chain complex, if not its homology?